# Loop to render Django view context as table in the template

Tags: python, django

I want to pass the following dictionary as context to Django template:

```
context = {'prices': prices, 'listings_links': listings_links, 'listings_names': listings_names, 'photo_links': photo_links}
```

The dictionary's values are lists.

In the template I want to display those lists as columns in HTML table. However I am not sure how to further develop the following skeleton table code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Link</th>
      <th>Listing name</th>
      <th>Photo link</th>
    </tr>
 {% for loop start here? %}
    <tr>
      <td> {{prices[0] }} </td>
      <td> {{ listings_links[0] }} </td>
      <td> {{ listings_names[0] }} </td>
      <td> {{ photo_links[0] }} </td>
    </tr>
    #next rows go here... 
 {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the view, zip your lists into a single iterable.

```
items = zip(prices, listings_links, listings_names, photo_links)

context = {'items': item}
```

Then you can unpack `items` in the template:

```
{% for price, listing_link, listing_name, photo_link in items %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ prices }}</td>
    <td>{{ listing_link }}</td>
    <td>{{ listing_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ photo_link }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! On a side note, I am creating my lists from pandas DataFrame columns, and then rendering them to template using your method. Do you know if there is a faster way to extract DataFrame columns straight into table template like the one above?

Comment: I haven't used pandas so I can't help with that.